# How to make dropdown menu close when opening another one

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Hy!Im a iniciant in javascript.
I'm having trouble closing the dropdown when clicking on another open one.

I try this:

```
        on('click', '.navbar .dropdown > a', function(e) {
        if (select('#navbar').classList.contains('navbar-mobile')) {
          e.preventDefault()
          this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('dropdown-active')
        } else {
    this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('dropdown-active');
    } 
      }, true)
```

[dropdown image opened items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSjHZ.png)
[Codepen code](https://codepen.io/jefdoria/pen/YzvbJQq)

**Thank you for any help!**

Comment: Select the element with the active class and remove it.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in your codepen - the menus are dropping down and are not staying open when the mouse moves off the drop down. Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: In the dropdown, when I click on an item and click on another, the first item does not close, both remain open.

Answer (score 0):

a few days later.
this is my solution:

Use **querySelectorAll + forEach** in **.dropdown-active** and then remove the class

```
on('click', '.navbar .dropdown > a', function (e) {
    if (select('#navbar').classList.contains('navbar-mobile')) {
      e.preventDefault()
      document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-active").forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.remove("dropdown-active");
      });
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('dropdown-active')
    }
  }, true)
```